# Chrome Extension Link not working... (might be the connected js)

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension

It doesn't seem like there should be an issue because I added 4chan to the permissions potion of the manifest, but the link still doesn't open up a new tab to 4chan.org. Please if anyone can tell whats wrong with my code I'd really appreciate it.

Here is my current code:

manifest.json:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "C-List",
"description": "Never Miss a New Thread Again",
"version": "3.0",

"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.jpg",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
"tabs",
"activeTab",
"https://www.4chan.org/",
"http://www.google.com/"
]
}
```

popup.html:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>C-List</title>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background-color:rgb(0,255,80)"></div>
<h3>A New Thread Has Been Posted</h3>
<!-- <a id = "link">4Chan</a>
<a href="https://4chan.org/" class="button">Go to Google</a>
<button id="checkPage">Check it out now!</button>
--> 
<button type="button"><a href="https://4chan.org/" class="button">New   Thread</a></button>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js:**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('checkPage');
checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  d = document;

  var f = d.createElement('form');
  f.action = 'https://4chan.org/';
  f.method = 'post';
  var i = d.createElement('input');
  i.type = 'hidden';
  i.name = 'url';
  i.value = tab.url;
  f.appendChild(i);
  d.body.appendChild(f);
  //f.submit();
  });
  }, false);
  }, false);
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
chrome.tabs.create({'url': "https://4chan.org/"});
});
/*
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var link = document.getElementById('checkPage');
// onClick's logic below:
link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    hellYeah('xxx');
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[`chrome.browserAction.onClicked`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked) events don't fire when there is a popup defined for your [`browser_action`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction). You get *either* the popup opened *or* the `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` event, not both. Which you get depends entirely on if there is a popup page specified (in your [*manifest.json*](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) or set with [`browserAction.setPopup()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setPopup)).

So, you are going to need to add an event listener for your button. Something like:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.create({'url': "https://4chan.org/"});
});
```